# How to create gcloud dataflow from linux console

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, console, gcloud, dataflow

I have already created gcloud dataflow on the Google cloud platform and now I need to do it from the Linux console. The main questions:

- How should it look?
- How can I work with --parameters of gcloud?

Answer (score 1):

Generally (!) everything that you can achieve through Cloud Console, is available to you through the Google Cloud SDK more commonly referred to as `gcloud`.

`gcloud` is well-designed, consistent and more powerful than the Console; you have more power and flexibility using `gcloud` than Console.

I recommend you consult Google's `gcloud` documentation ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference)). On the left hand side, you will see an enumeration of all the commands with detailed documentation.

I recommend you consider using the excellent [gcloud interactive shell](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/interactive-gcloud) too. This will facilitate your learning of the tool.

One caveat with `gcloud` is that there are generally-available commands (`gcloud [command] ...`) and there are alpha and beta commands too. Personally, I find this confusing because you may need to consult three different commands to find exactly what you need.

In your case, `gcloud dataflow --help` will inform you that you can interact with one 'group' only (`jobs`), i.e. `gcloud dataflow jobs --help`. However, if you use the alpha and beta commands, `gcloud alpha dataflow --help`, you will see that you're able to interact with `jobs`, `logs` and `metrics`. Be mindful of this with all the `gcloud` commands.

A good starting point for you may be to query (non-destructively) `jobs` in your project. The documentation shows two options `list` ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/list)) and `describe` ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataflow/jobs/describe)).

Because all `gcloud` commands are scoped to a Cloud Project, you will need to specify the project. You can do this per command `gcloud ... --project=${PROJECT}` or you can set the project as a default `gcloud config set project ${PROJECT}`. I recommend you always specify the project per command.

So, without further ado... this should get you going:

Optionally, use the interactive shell (NB one of the `beta` commands):

```
gcloud beta interactive
```

If not already, login:

```
gcloud auth login [[YOUR-GOOGLE-ACCOUNT]]
```

Then something similar to:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
```

Grab one of the job IDs:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs describe [[YOUR-JOB-ID]] --project=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
```